# not null not working in Pyspark when using impala jdbc driver

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am new to Pyspark. I am using Impala JDBC driver ImpalaJDBC41.jar . In my pyspark code, I use the below.

```
df =  spark.read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", "jdbc:impala://<instance>:21051") \
      .option("query", "select dst_val,node_name,trunc(starttime,'SS') as starttime from def.tbl_dst where node_name is not null and trunc(starttime,'HH') >= trunc(hours_add(now(),-1),'HH') and trunc(starttime,'HH') < trunc(now(),'HH')") \
      .option("user", "") \
      .option("password", "") \
      .load()
```

But the above does not work and the "node_name is not null" is not working. Also the trunc(starttime,'SS') is also not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sample input data :

dst_val,node_name,starttime
BCD098,,2021-03-26 15:42:06.890000000
BCD043,HKR_NODEF,2021-03-26 20:31:09
BCD038,BCF_NODEK,2021-03-26 21:29:10


Expected output :

dst_val,node_name,starttime
BCD043,HKR_NODEF,2021-03-26 20:31:09
BCD038,BCF_NODEK,2021-03-26 21:29:10
```

For debugging , I am tryin to print the df.show. But no use.
I am using df.show() , but it is still showing the record with null. The datatype of node_name is "STRING"

Answer (score 0):

can you please use this ?

```
select dst_val,node_name,cast( from_timestamp(starttime,'SSS') as bigint) as starttime from def.tbl_dst where (node_name is not null or node_name<>'' ) and trunc(starttime,'HH') >= trunc(hours_add(now(),-1),'HH') and trunc(starttime,'HH') < trunc(now(),'HH')
```

I think `node_name` has empty space in it and above sql(i added `or node_name<>''`) will take care of it.
Now, if you have some non-printable character, then we may have to check accordingly.

EDIT : Since not null is working in Impala, i think this may be a spark issue.

Comment: I tired. It does not work. those are actual null values.

Comment: If you run it from hive command prompt/shell, do you get data?

Comment: if i run this as a direct impala query , the "not null" works, but the timestamp with miliseconds is still getting missed

Comment: `cast( from_timestamp(starttime,'SSS') as bigint)` - This will give you milliseconds.